# Flink package missing class CheckpointCommitter - flink-connector-cassandra - hard error

Tags: cassandra, apache-flink

I'm getting this error when submitting a new job to Flink (v 1.0.3) in my local environment.

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/streaming/runtime/operators/CheckpointCommitter
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.cassandra.CassandraSink.addSink(CassandraSink.java:164)
    at com.xxx.yyy.sample.backend.flink.AAAAA.main(AAAAA.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:505)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:403)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.OptimizerPlanEnvironment.getOptimizedPlan(OptimizerPlanEnvironment.java:80)
    ... 33 more
Looking at the source code in github

https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/runtime/operators

i would think that the class should be available and it should be packaged in flink-streaming-java.jar but once the file is imported, the class is not there

[missing CheckpointCommitter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwVu0.png)

Any ideas?

pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.AAAAA.BBB</groupId>
<artifactId>sample-backend-flink</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Flink Quickstart Job</name>
<url>http://www.myorganization.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <flink.version>1.0.3</flink.version>
    <cassandra.version>2.2.7</cassandra.version>
    <driver.version>3.0.0</driver.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>apache.snapshots</id>
        <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-clients_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.8_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-cassandra_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-redis_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- Profile for packaging correct JAR files -->
        <id>build-jar</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
                <version>${flink.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.10</artifactId>
                <version>${flink.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                <artifactId>flink-streaming-scala_2.10</artifactId>
                <version>${flink.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                <artifactId>flink-clients_2.10</artifactId>
                <version>${flink.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId>
                <version>${flink.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.8_2.10</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                <artifactId>flink-connector-cassandra_2.10</artifactId>
                <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                <artifactId>flink-connector-redis_2.10</artifactId>
                <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <!-- disable the exclusion rules -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>shade</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <artifactSet>
                                    <excludes combine.self="override"></excludes>
                                </artifactSet>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <excludes><exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-annotations</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-hadoop1</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-hadoop2</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-curator-recipes</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-core</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-java</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-scala_2.10</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-runtime_2.10</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-optimizer_2.10</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-clients_2.10</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-avro_2.10</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-examples-batch_2.10</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-examples-streaming_2.10</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-java_2.10</exclude>


                                <exclude>org.scala-lang:scala-library</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.scala-lang:scala-compiler</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.scala-lang:scala-reflect</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_*</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.typesafe.akka:akka-remote_*</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j_*</exclude>
                                <exclude>io.netty:netty-all</exclude>
                                <exclude>io.netty:netty</exclude>
                                <exclude>commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.avro:avro</exclude>
                                <exclude>commons-collections:commons-collections</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.commons:commons-compress</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.tukaani:xz</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.esotericsoftware.minlog:minlog</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.objenesis:objenesis</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.twitter:chill_*</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.twitter:chill-java</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.twitter:chill-avro_*</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.twitter:chill-bijection_*</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.twitter:bijection-core_*</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.twitter:bijection-avro_*</exclude>
                                <exclude>commons-lang:commons-lang</exclude>
                                <exclude>junit:junit</exclude>
                                <exclude>de.javakaffee:kryo-serializers</exclude>
                                <exclude>joda-time:joda-time</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.commons:commons-lang3</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.slf4j:slf4j-api</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12</exclude>
                                <exclude>log4j:log4j</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.commons:commons-math</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.sling:org.apache.sling.commons.json</exclude>
                                <exclude>commons-logging:commons-logging</exclude>
                                <exclude>commons-codec:commons-codec</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations</exclude>
                                <exclude>stax:stax-api</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.typesafe:config</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.uncommons.maths:uncommons-maths</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.github.scopt:scopt_*</exclude>
                                <exclude>commons-io:commons-io</exclude>
                                <exclude>commons-cli:commons-cli</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </artifactSet>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>org.apache.flink:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <!-- exclude shaded google but include shaded curator -->
                                    <exclude>org/apache/flink/shaded/com/**</exclude>
                                    <exclude>web-docs/**</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                            <filter>
                                <!-- Do not copy the signatures in the META-INF folder.
                                Otherwise, this might cause SecurityExceptions when using the JAR. -->
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <transformers>
                            <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.demandware.unified.sample.backend.flink.PhysicalInventory</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source> <!-- If you want to use Java 8, change this to "1.8" -->
                <target>1.8</target> <!-- If you want to use Java 8, change this to "1.8" -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Could you share your Maven pom with us? It might help solving your issue.

Comment: I've added a reference to the redis connector and now i get the same error but for another class,

Comment: I've added a reference to the redis connector and now i get the same error but for another class, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/util/Preconditions, again i checked in github the class is in the right place github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/flink-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/util but when i ope flink-core.jar the class is not in there.

Comment: your pom contains references to several different versions of Flink. Mentioned versions i found are `1.0.2`, `1.0.3` and `1.1-SNAPSHOT`. Please decide for one version to use; i would assume that this will fix your issue.

Comment: @ChesnaySchepler, the multiple versions do not make a difference, beleve me, i've tried all the combinations and none of them work

Comment: Just to clarify, the errors are not at compile time, they are at run time, meaning that the 1.0.x flink jar does not contains the classes referenced avobe

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. What fixed for me was ensuring the KafkaConsumer/Producer used in the source matches the one you depend on.

There seems to be a conflict between the differing versions of FlinkKafkaConsumer.

When using this import

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.8_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

make sure you are using [FlinkKafkaConsumer08](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/FlinkKafkaConsumer08.html) rather than [FlinkKafkaConsumer](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.9/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/FlinkKafkaConsumer.html) (Or Producer if you are using the producer)

The weird thing for me is that my IDE cannot resolve the FlinkKafkaConsumer08, but it compiles using a build tool and runs correctly.